# Date Format Validation

Tags: c#

How to make sure only this date format which is being entered in the console is being accepted and stored in the text file and any other should not be stored in the text file and should display an error message prompting the user to enter the date in correct format.

```
Date Format = MM/DD/YYYY
```

---

Using the following code 13/10/2013 displays the error message but even while entering the correct format like 12/12/2013 it displays the same error message and keeps repeating itself and if doesn't validate the correct format. return suspends the application.

```
if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date,"MM-dd-yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None,out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid date format!");
    while(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date,"MM-dd-yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None,out date))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Date Entered, please format MM-dd-yyyy");
        Date = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

String builder and other concepts are not allowed. What to do?

---

I accept the user's input as string and later check, if it is in correct format and then convert it back to string if it adheres to the specified format and then it will get stored in my text file only if the user has entered the correct date format.

---

```
public override bool IsValid(string value)
{
    string format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    DateTime dt;

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact((String)value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        return IsValid(dt);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Can the code above be modified and fused with my code to get it working?

Comment: You've asked the question multiple times, every single time you have gotten the same answer: If you want to parse a date that is entered like `08/05/2013`, you CANNOT try to match it with the string `MM-dd-yyyy` because it has `-` instead of `/`. Since you clearly think that answer is inadequate, can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

change the format as `"MM/dd/yyyy"`

if you need validate date format with `MM/dd/yyyy` you need to give it as the format string in the `TryParseExact` method, curently you have `MM-dd-yyyy`. so you need to give input something like `01-01-2013`

Answer (score 1):

This following code will work:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Date Scheduled For the Meeting:");
            string Date = Console.ReadLine();
            DateTime Test;
            if(DateTime.TryParseExact(Date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out Test) == true)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("Date is in the correct Format");
            }
            else
            {
                     Console.Write("Date Not OK");
                     return;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your format is MM/DD/YYYY, why are you parsing MM-DD-YYYY?

```
 while(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date,"MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out date))
```